# Executar condição (if/else) que está dentro de uma string em c# 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Eu possuo uma classe que gera arquivos `csv` a partir de uma consulta, e esse arquivo pode ter vários `templates`, alguns com condições para exibir valor `x` ou `y`.

Essas condições estão dentro de uma base de dados e quando recupero esses dados a expressão vem dentro de uma `string`. Utilizei `Reflection` para fazer isso e funcionou, porém onerou muito a performance da aplicação, tendo em vista que são muitas linhas.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum outro modo de executar uma expressão de `if` que está dentro de uma `string`.

Exemplo do `if`:

```
string Exp = "A == B ? 123 : 345"
```

Segue a função que fiz:

```
string source = @"
    namespace cond
    {
        public class Bar
        {
            public string resultadoexpressao()
            {
                return "+expressao+";
            }
        }
    }";

Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
        {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}
};

CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
{
    GenerateInMemory = false,
    GenerateExecutable = false
};

CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);

object o = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("cond.Bar");

MethodInfo mi = o.GetType().GetMethod("resultadoexpressao");

string resultado = (string)mi.Invoke(o, null);   

return resultado;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver com tempo, e tiver com vontade de aprender algo legal, você pode criar um **parser de expressões** bem simples para isso.

Uma receita boa para se seguir em um parser é criar os métodos de leitura assim:

```
DadoDeRetorno LerAlgumaCoida(string codigo, ref int pos)
{
    // lê algo do código e avança a posição de leitura
}
```

Esse `DadoDeRetorno` depende do que você quer fazer.

- **interpretar:** nesse caso a saída da maioria dos métodos é o resultado obtido da interpretação. Como você não vai saber de antemão o tipo a ser retornado, então vai ser `object` mesmo.
- **gerar árvore sintática:** nesse caso a saída será um nó de árvore sintática. Esse é o caso por exemplo, de você querer usar Expression Trees, do LINQ, as quais você pode depois compilar, o que vai te dar um grande ganho de performance.
- **compilar:** poucas linguagens podem ser compiladas diretamente do código, mas um parser de expressões provavelmente é uma exceção. Neste caso, você provavelmente irá querer retornar uma string/array já com a tradução para a linguagem de destino.

Para cada coisa que for lida com sucesso, você deve atualizar a variável `pos`.
Além disso, o retorno de cada função deve indicar se o método teve sucesso ou não para facilitar as coisas.

Você vai precisar de métodos como esse modelo para ler espaços, para ler nomes de variáveis, para ler números, entre outros:

```
bool LerEspacos(string codigo, ref int pos); // retorna false se não ler nada
string LerNomeDeVariavel(string codigo, ref int pos); // retorna null se não ler nada
int? LerNumeroInteiro(string codigo, ref int pos); // retorna null se não ler nada
```

Cada uma também pode receber outros valores pertinentes a cada tipo de parser.
Por exemplo, ao fazer um interpretador, é preciso passar os valores das variáveis. Se for um compilador, talvez seja preciso passar um lista dos registradores em uso e talvez até alterar essa lista.

Também vai precisar de um método para processar as expressões. Esse entra no mesmo modelo, mas dentro dele, a implementação é um pouquinho mais complicada.

```
Expression LerExpressao(string codigo, ref int pos, Contexto contexto);
```

Para esse caso você precisa de duas pilhas, uma de operadores, e outra de operandos.

Sempre que um operando for achado, você empilha ele na lista de operandos.

Quando um operador for achado, você precisa empilhar ele na pilha de operadores, mas somente se ele possuir maior precedência que o que já está na pilha. Caso contrário, é necessário executar a operação que está na pilha com os operandos que estão na pilha de operandos.

Exemplo dos passos de um interpretador com duas pilhas:

```
Entrada: 1 + 3 * 5 + 8

// Lê 1 da entrada e põe na pilha de operandos
Operandos: 1
Operadores: 

Entrada: + 3 * 5 + 8

// Lê "+" da entrada e põe na pilha de operadores
Operandos: 1
Operadores: +

Entrada: 3 * 5 + 8

// Lê 3 da entrada e põe na pilha de operandos
Operandos: 1 3
Operadores: +

Entrada: * 5 + 8

// Lê "*" da entrada e põe na pilha de operadores
Operandos: 1 3
Operadores: + *

Entrada: 5 + 8

// Lê 5 da entrada e põe na pilha de operandos
Operandos: 1 3 5
Operadores: + *

Entrada: + 8

// Não pode empilhar + sobre *
// Executa a operação 3 * 5 = 15
// Remove o operador * da pilha
// Remove os operandos 3 e 5 da pilha
// Adiciona o 15 e o + nas respectivas pilhas
Operandos: 1 15
Operadores: + +

Entrada: 8

Operandos: 1 15 8
Operadores: + +

// Acabou, agora basta ir executando todos os itens das pilhas
// 15 + 8 = 23

Operandos: 1 23
Operadores: +

// 1 + 23 = 24

Operandos: 24
Operadores:

// o resultado é o que sobra na pilha de operandos = 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Se a expressão está salva no banco de dados, pode alterar ela para o próprio SQL executar o `if/else`, no caso, se for SQL Server, mude a condição para um `case`, gere a consulta dinamicamente, carregando os dados das tabelas parametrizadas e a  execute com o sp_sqlexec e retorne o valor já tratado **123** ou **345**.